Any other 3d plot marker except sphere for ListLinePlot3D?
Here is one sample Mathematica code:
B0 = {{0.1, 0.0, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.3, 0.45}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.37}, {0.1, 0.9, 
    0.33}, {0.1, 1.2, 0.27}};
B1 = {{0.1, 0.0, 0.47}, {0.1, 0.3, 0.41}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.31}, {0.1, 0.9,
     0.28}, {0.1, 1.2, 0.23}};

ListLinePlot3D[{B0, B1}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"Sphere", Medium}, {"Sphere", Tiny}}]

Is there any way I can use other 3d shaped figures similar to Sphere like a pyramid or say cube as a PlotMarker here?

There are no other predefined markers besides "Point" and "Sphere", but you can use any Graphics3D you want.
marker1 = Graphics3D[{Red, Cube[]}, Boxed -> False];
marker2 = Graphics3D[{Green, Icosahedron[]}, Boxed -> False];
ListLinePlot3D[{B0, B1}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{marker1, Scaled[0.1]}, {marker2, Scaled[0.1]}}, BoxRatios -> 1]



Ah, that's neat. Thanks for the answer.

great answer. I tried a similar approach but did not work. Do you know why the markers are not centered at the points?

@alex, can you please explain in more details what you mean by "not centered at the points"? As I see it, they are centered, it's just the clipping of the marker that gets somehow wonky ...

This is what I wanted to understand. Why is there weird clipping and is it deliberate to permit the line to be visible?
For what it is worth, it solves my issue as well, but it seems that it is really struggling! appears too computationally heavy for my PC. It feels like it should be a lightweight solution... A similar approach using BubbleChart3D appears far more lightweight.
